# salesforce dataloader installation problem

Tags: salesforce, dataloader

I am learning salesforce. I am trying to install dataloader. I have downloaded and extracted the files in the zip file, into a local folder.

But when I am trying to run the install.bat, I get this error.

```
2023-08-14 19:08:29,778 FATAL [main] install.Installer handleException 
(Installer.java:392) - Installer :
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\Santu%20Ghosh\Documents\temp\dataloader-58.0.3.jar
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:53) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:38) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:198) ~[?:?]
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1764) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1250) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:733) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:842) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:248) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:177) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:350) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:321) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:287) ~[?:?]
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.util.AppUtil.extractDirFromJar(AppUtil.java:178) ~[dataloader-58.0.3.jar:?]
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.install.Installer.extractInstallationArtifactsFromJar(Installer.java:378) [dataloader-58.0.3.jar:?]
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.install.Installer.install(Installer.java:100) [dataloader-58.0.3.jar:?]
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.DataLoaderRunner.runApp(DataLoaderRunner.java:102) [dataloader-58.0.3.jar:?]
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.DataLoaderRunner.main(DataLoaderRunner.java:84) [dataloader-58.0.3.jar:?]
 Data Loader installation is quitting.
```

I have java 11 installed in my system.
Can anyone guide me what is possibly wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am experiencing this issue too. I installed Data Loader V57.0.1 and it worked on the first try.
Here is the Data Loader release that worked for me: https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/releases/tag/v57.0.1

Comment: Hi Allan. I downloaded 57.0.1. and was able to install it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The filepath cant have a space in it. moving it to a path with no space and it worked just fine from there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can't just point the path to the install directory but you need the files that are in the zip moved to the folder before installation - try this if you are having issues:

1. Install java jdk zulu
2. Unzip the total contents of data loader into a folder
3. For windows run the "install" windows batch file inside the folder you just extracted the zip to, do NOT use the install file inside the original zip
4. type yes to install in the same folder that includes the files from the zip file

Answer (score 0):

Credit : [@alan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22448416/allan)

I am experiencing this issue too. I installed Data Loader V57.0.1 and it worked on the first try. Here is the Data Loader release that worked for me: https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/releases/tag/v57.0.1